# Portforward VNC connection with Nginx

Tags: nginx, portforwarding

I would like to port forward the VNC connection with nginx on ubuntu, from port 59031 of the (public) ip of the server to ip 10.7.0.31 on port 5900, located on another server interface.
But this example code doesn't work.

```
server {
    listen 59031;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_pass http://10.7.0.31:5900;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I already do it on several other ports but for webserver connections and it works correctly, while for this VNC it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong? I already have the ports open on the firewall.
Thanks